# Recognizing ellipse's shapes OpenCV

Tags: opencv, contour

I work with Opencv on ellipses' form, I want to separate between vertical ellipses and horizontal ones.

Have you any idea how can I do it ?

Comment: you will have to estimate orientation vectors from the image after some processing (like edge detection and segmentation), the segmentation can color the eclipse and the estimation of orientation can be done at least this way, i'll have to check for other approaches as well

Comment: can you give some sample images?

Comment: You tagged the question with contour so i assume that you got the contour already. In your next step you should use the fitEllipse() function in OpenCV and save the return in a RotatedRect. The RotatedRect contains an angle property you can use to seperate between vertical and horizontal ellipses.

Comment: @David_D how can i use RotatedRect.angle to seperate between vertical and horizontal ellipses.

Comment: i had thoose values of RotatedRect.angle

Comment: angle :173.566
angle :176.099
angle :8.30595
angle :172.143
angle :172.141
angle :171.746
angle :173.68
angle :176.399
angle :174.218

Comment: @LouaýEssaaÐi http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rotatedrect angle – The rotation angle in a clockwise direction. When the angle is near 90 or 270 you should have a vertical ellipse. With an angle near 0 or 180 it should be horizontal.

Comment: thunk you all for your attention